# Determining "noise" in bandwidth data

Tags: python, r, statistics

I'm have bandwidth data which identifies protocol usage by tonnage and hour. Based on the protocols, you can tell when something is just connect vs actually being used (1000 bits compared to million or billions of bits) in that hour for that specific protocol. The problem is When looking at each protocol, they are all heavily right skewed. Where 80% of the records are the just connected or what I'm calling "noise.

The task I have is to separate out this noise and focus on only when the protocol is actually being used. My classmates are all just doing this manually and removing at a low threshold. I was hoping there was a way to automate this and using statistics instead of just picking a threshold that "looks good." We have something like 30 different protocols each with a different amount of bits which would represent "noise" i.e. a download prototypical might have 1000 bits where a messaging app might have 75 bits when they are connected but not in full use. Similarly they will have different means and gaps between i.e. download mean is 215,000,000 and messaging is 5,000,000. There isn't any set pattern between them.

Also this "noise" has many connections but only accounts for 1-3% of the total bandwidth being used, this is why we are tasked with identify actual usage vs passive usage.

I don't want any actual code, as I'd like to practice with the implementation and solution building myself. But the logic, process, or name of a statistical method would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have labeled examples, and do you have other data besides the bandwidth? One way to do this would be to train some kind of ML classifier if you have a decent amount of data where you know it's either in use or not in use. If you have enough data you also might be able to do this unsupervised. For a start a simple Naive Bayes classifier works well for binary solutions. As you may be away, NB was the original bases for spam detection (is it spam or not). So your case of is it noise or not should also work, but you will get more robust results if you have other data in addition to the bandwidth to train on. Also, I am wondering if there isn't a way to improve the title of your post so that it communicates your question more quickly.